# Parsing XML and checking values against an elements value

Tags: xml, kotlin

I am trying to validate a user's username and password by parsing my XML file filled with users. Currently, my method is coming back as false. It is supposed to go through the child elements of `<users>` and find the user with the username given, and check the password against the parameters of `checkUser()`.

I cannot seem to get access to the text inside of the `<password>` element.

Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
fun checkUser(username: String, password: String) : Boolean {
    val xmlFile = File("Users.xml")
    val doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlFile)
    var list = doc.getElementsByTagName("user")
    for (i in 0 until list.length) {
        var current = list.item(i)
        if (current.attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue == username) {
            return current.lastChild.textContent == password //trying to check text against given password
        }
    }
    return false
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(checkUser("alec", "123")) //returns false right now
}
```

Here is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<users>
    <user id="alec">
        <username>alec</username>
        <password>123</password>
    </user>
    <user id="john">
        <username>john</username>
        <password>415</password>
    </user>
</users>
```

**EDIT**

`current.attributes.item(0)` returns a node, but I need to get the attribute `id` inside the `<user>` tag and check it against the given username.

**EDIT**
Fixed code to get id and compare to `username` parameter, still returns false

Comment: It might be worthwhile to look at getting XPath to work. Manual iteration of a nodelist is fine for simple tasks, but it's very easy to get into an area where a more expressive way of finding a node helps.

Comment: (On a more general note, please don't store unencrypted passwords in a file.)

Comment: @Tomalak normally I would not, but it's for example application that will only be used for a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you println the size of the NodeList that is returned calling `current.childNodes` you will get 5. The first, third and last nodes are blank nodes. your data is in nodes 2 and 4. Therefore, you can replace your code with the following and it will work.

```
val xmlFile = File("Users.xml")
val doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlFile)
var list = doc.getElementsByTagName("user")
for (i in 0 until list.length) {
    var current = list.item(i)
    if (current.attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue == username) {
        println(current.childNodes.length)

        for (j in 0 until current.childNodes.length) {
            if (current.childNodes.item(j).nodeName == "password") {
                return current.childNodes.item(j).textContent == password
            }
        }
    }
}
return false
```

That said, I would be tempted to use a better XML parser, because this code is far more verbose than needed.

For example, with DOM4J, you can replace all of the above code with

```
val doc = SAXReader().read(File("users.xml"))
val users = doc.rootElement.elements("user")
for (user in users) {
    if (user.attribute("id").value == username) {
        return user.element("password").text == password
    }

}
return false
```

Comment: In your DOM4J sample, why is there a need for the `user is Element` check?

Comment: `rootElement.elements()` returns a `List` of `Node` objects. By Element check does a smart-cast to an Element object, as that is what we need for the username and password checks.

Comment: `.elements()` returns a list of elements, unless I'm reading the docs wrong.

Comment: You are correct. I switched from using doc.selectNodes, to doc.rootElement.elements(). SelectNodes, as the name suggests, does indeed return a list of nodes, and needs the smart cast, but elements returns Elements (again, as the name suggests), so does not need the cast. I will update the code to remove the unnecessary code.

Comment: `.elements('user')` would be more explicit (and maybe more resilient, too).

Comment: When i try to use `.attribute("id")` on `user`, it is not showing up as a method.

Comment: DOM4J is a third party library. You need to download it. https://dom4j.github.io/

Comment: @Codemwnci yes just realized my gradle was trying to use an old version of it